# How to create a blog page like this?

Tags: html, css, markdown, blogs

[Link here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

**More than Markdown**

- the head font is beautiful what is this?
- at the left there are pagination jump and section list.
- In text, the *Note referring Div* and *Reference referring Div* can abreast in one line.
- figure at right and text at left

[Link here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

How to make all this in Blogware method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The font is Roboto, very clear and cute font
2. You can use Wordpress to do beautifull websites, there are thousand of themes.
3. This apears to be ad hoc website, I don't think that there are a cms or another platform to archive similar website.
4. You need to use your skills and creativity to do your website, If you can't, you can paid to an expert in web design and development :D

Best

Comment: what means adhoc website ? You mean there is no template for this?